# Triggering automated tests with Jira/ Xray and GitHub Actions

Tags: triggers, github-actions, jira, manual, x-ray

I already integrated results of automated test with XRAY (from GitHub Actions)
But I would like to know if anyone knows how to manually trigger automated test from XRAY, pressing the "RUN" button in a test plan.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can run trigger manually form xray using Automation Rulu execution in JIRA .

follow this guides: [https://www.atlassian.com/devops/testing-tutorials/jira-xray-integration-trigger-automated-tests#:~:text=In%20Jira%20settings%2C%20under%20Automation,from%20the%20Test%20Plan%20issue](https://www.atlassian.com/devops/testing-tutorials/jira-xray-integration-trigger-automated-tests#:%7E:text=In%20Jira%20settings%2C%20under%20Automation,from%20the%20Test%20Plan%20issue).